# Error when attempting to dynamically change Select2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web project. I am currently using select2 for several dropdowns in my project, due to its clean and appealing features. I am also having some problems with select2. I am wanting to create a dropdown on a create page that 'changes' state when another dropdown value is changed. Select2 has a drop-down that offers both the ability to select from the dropdown results OR type your own entry in and save. (see the *tagging* section on https://select2.github.io/examples.html). I need to be able to turn tags on/off dynamically through javascript **AFTER** page load. It seems that select2 will only initialize the dropdown and after that, it won't allow dynamic changes.

View Html and Javascript code used to *initialize* select2 on page load:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
   @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.modelNum, Model.modelNumList, new { @class= "js-tags" })
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">    

        $(".js-tags").select2({
            placeholder: "Enter Model",
            tags: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 1
        })

</script>
```

The above part works great. Select2 is initialized, and follows my settings. After this, my plan is to change the settings of the select2 my destroying and reinitializing the instance, therefore *editing the dropdown and turning tags back off*. The below javascript method is called when another dropdown is changed.

CODE:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function ChangeModelNum(_classID)
   {
       if(_classID == 1)
       {
           $(".js-tags").select2("destroy").select2({
               placeholder: "Select Model",

               tags: false,
               maximumSelectionLength: 1
           })             
       }
       else
       {
           $(".js-tags").select2({
               placeholder: "Enter Model",
               tags: true,
               maximumSelectionLength: 1
           })
       }
   }
```

As you can see, if the user selects the classID as 1, I want to disable tagging for the dropdown. But it simply doesn't work. I also get this error in developer tools:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'select2'

I have made sure there are no double jquery references also. It makes no sense why it has an error with Select2 right after using it perfectly.

***ADDITION:***

Here is the code that triggers ChangeModelNum:

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.classnum, Model.classL, "Select Class", new { @onchange = "javascript:ChangeModelNum(this.value);", @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think that this particular error could be caused by method chaining

```
$(".js-tags").select2("destroy").select2...
```

Try to split it to two separate calls:

```
$(".js-tags").select2("destroy");
$(".js-tags").select2({
               placeholder: "Select Model",
               tags: false,
               maximumSelectionLength: 1
           })
```

Comment: Can you show the code that triggers ChangeModelNum? when do bind this to change event? Could it be that ChangeModelNum is triggered before select2 was initialized?

Comment: instead of `@onchange = "javascript:ChangeModelNum(this.value);"` assign an id to this dropdown and subscribe to the event on document ready:
`$(document).ready(function(){$("#dropDownId").change(function(){
ChangeModelNum($(this).val())
})})`

Comment: This code gives me syntax error, something about one of the parenthesis. I am not experienced with javascript so I am having trouble implementing this, and can't fix the error